# Нужна помощь с литературными аргументами к сочинению.

Tags: егэ, анализ-текста

Не могу придумать второй аргумент. Исходный текст: [link text](http://s012.radikal.ru/i319/1401/8c/eccf95ba325c.png)    [link text](http://s020.radikal.ru/i713/1401/6f/425b40dd91df.png)

Вот что я написал:

```
      Предложенный для анализа текст выдающегося советского филолога и культуролога Юрия Михайловича Лотмана посвящен проблеме воспитания нового поколения. Что необходимо сознательно культивировать в семье и в школе? Чему необходимо приучать детей в первую очередь?
      Автор заставляет читателя задуматься над тем, как часто родители предпочитают давать детям готовые выводы, не вызывая напряжения интеллекта, не направляя их к духовному поиску. Это может привести к духовному потребительству, считает он.
      Ю.Лотман подводит читателя к выводу о том, что самое главное в воспитании это приучать детей к самостоятельности, активной работе мысли и совести.
      Я целиком и полностью разделяю и горячо поддерживаю позицию автора, и тоже считаю, что даже при постижении простейших законов жизни взрослые должны приобщать детей к самостоятельности. Тогда дети сами постепенно начнут решать свои, хоть и кажущиеся для взрослых маленькими, но все же, проблемы.
      Приведу литературные аргументы, подтверждающие мою позицию. В качестве первого примера хочу привести комедию Д.И.Фонвизина «Недоросль». Простакова-мать Митрофана, называет вздором все, что не ведает ее дитя, опекает его во всем, а Митрофан, пользуясь этим уклоняется от учебы. В итоге из Митрофана вырастает убогое в нравственном плане существо: он никого не любит, никого не жалеет, не имеет никаких моральных обязательств. 
      Также, А.Г.Алексин в рассказе "Безумная Евдокия" рисует образ учителя,который воспитывает прежде всего нравственность, доброту. Родители Оленьки говорили, что она несправедлива к их дочери. Они думали, что она талантливее всех в классе, их слепая любовь воспитала в ней эгоистку, забывшую своих родителей, которые потом часто вспоминали о правоте учителя. Главное - воспитать доброго человека.
      Итак, чрезмерно опекать детей, не давать им свободу для действий, не следует, так как самое главное в воспитании – это развитие духовного мира подрастающего поколения и приобщение его к самостоятельности. Только тогда в нашем обществе будет много добрых, отзывчивых и справедливых людей.
```

Comment: Видимо, в сознании ertgeg'a "советский литературовед, культуролог и семиотик" Ю.М. Лотман превратился в "известного русского филолога и культуролога" Ю.М. Лотмана.

Comment: Спасибо, поправил.

Comment: Dear ertgeg.

Ваше первое предложение можно изложить в следующей редакции: "Предложенный нами для всестороннего анализа текст выдающегося советского филолога и культуролога Юрия Михайловича Лотмана посвящен проблеме воспитания нового поколения строителей коммунизма в одной, отдельно взятой стране."

Comment: Dear ertgeg.

Выражение "Я полностью разделяю позицию автора" можно изложить внушительнее, а именно: "Я целиком и полностью разделяю и горячо поддерживаю позицию дорогого и любимого Юрия Михайловича, ..."

Comment: Никому обычно не интересно читать ещё одно высказывание об очередном согласии с автором. Гораздо более интригующим был бы такой зачин:

>Я полностью разделяю (и даже горячо поддерживаю) позицию автора в части приобщения к самостоятельности, но...

\- и далее куча примеров, плавно подводящих читателей к мысли о том, что детей надо держать в ежовых рукавицах.

Comment: Нравится!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  посвящен проблеме воспитания нового поколения строителей коммунизма в одной, отдельно взятой стране. Что необходимо сознательно культивировать в семье и в школе? Чему необходимо приучать детей в первую очередь?
```

Где это Вы в тексте нашли про строителей коммунизма? Это из прошлого века. А Лотман размышляет о закономерностях в истории человечества и о проблемах воспитания. Проблема воспитания - верно, но ни о каких "строителях" речи нет. Его интересует,что является главным в современном воспитании. Дальше - верно. Но комментарий неглубок. Автор говорит о двух сторонах воспитания - воспитании творчества и самостоятельности мышления и о воспитании духовных потребностей.

Его позиция: самое главное - развивать духовный мир, приучать к активной работе мысли и совести.

"Недоросль" - хороший аргумент, можно было ещё сказать о его"не хочу учиться - хочу жениться" и о том, что на первом месте среди ценностей  у него богатство,а мозг неразвит, пользы государству от него никакой.

А.Алексин в рассказе "Безумная Евдокия" рисует образ учителя,который воспитывает прежде всего нравственность, доброту. Родители Оленьки говорили, что она несправедлива к их дочери, которая талантливее всех в классе, их слепая любовь воспитала эгоистку, забывшую своих родителей, которые потом часто вспоминали о правоте учителя. Главное - воспитать доброго человека.

Comment: Но на этом месте вдруг

Оборвал старушку внук:

"Слушай, бабка, если так

Всё тебе знакомо,

Ты давай, сама езжай,

А я останусь дома."

P.S. Также к вопросу об употреблении слова "езжай" в русском языке.

Comment: Дай бог, чтоб Вашему ребёнку или внуку так же ответили при его обращении за помощью.